# Salesforce : Adding Component to Standard Page Layout

Tags: salesforce

I have created a component which is related to display standard state and country picklists on custom objects.

I am having trouble to add that component to standard VF page.

Is there a way I can add a component to the VF page?

Answer (score 0):

`<apex:page standardController="Account">
   This is my <i>page</i>. <br/>
   <c:myComponent/>
</apex:page>`

Replace `<c:myComponent/>` with `<YourNameSpace:myComponent/>` if `component` is defined in different `namespace`. [See Docs](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_comp_cust_using.htm)

Comment: Hi Mansoor, I want the component on standard page layout. I did created a VF page and included the component in it. Also I added the VF page to the standard page layout but the component fields are only visible in edit mode. I want the component fields to be visible for new pagelayout i.e when we create a new record, as well. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: I am afraid that there is no clean way to do that instead adding `Component-> VF pages -> Page Layout`. Can you share details what fields are not showing in the detail page..?